# Перетаскивание объекта в 3D Unity

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно перетащить куб относительно поворота камеры, например, как на этой демонстрации, или как в blender при нажатии кнопки g[image: Демонстрация]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` предварительно сохранив расстояние до объекта перед началом перетаскивания:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform obj;

    private Camera cam;

    private Vector2 mousePos;
    private Vector3 point;

    private float distance;


    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        distance = Vector3.Distance(cam.transform.position, obj.position);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

        point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, distance));

        obj.position = point;
    }
}
```